# Perform crud operation into another site collection using server object model

Tags: site-collection

I want to perform crud operation into a list which is into another site collection. How can i perform this operation using Server side object model?

Comment: I think there is no difference with the same site collection.
SPSite site -> SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb() -> SPList list = web.GetList(); ... Please add some details about your task

Comment: How will i create the context of another web application ?

Comment: what operations in SSOM do you need the context for?